# INSERT IGNORE INTO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My code looks like this (relevant parts):

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');

$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$device_id =$obj['device_id'];
$num =$obj['sensor_value'];
$sensor_value =intval($num);
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
$fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); 

    $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO rr_emergency SET `device_id` = $device_id, `sensor_value` = $sensor_value, `date_time` = $fdate;";
    $result = $dbh->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Nothing gets posted to my database using this syntax. I'm trying to only insert a new record if a record doesn't exist with the same `device_id` value.

And, yes, I know this code appears to be at risk for SQL injection...the data comes from another webservice that I control, so that isn't an issue here.

Answer (score 2):

When sending queries with values, you should use parameterized queries.  I suspect that is your problem.  You can fix the root cause or you add single quotes for the string and date values.  I would recommend the more standard syntax:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO rr_emergency(device_id, sensor_value, date_time)
    VALUES($device_id, $sensor_value, '$fdate')";
```

Note:  the error that you are getting is a compile-time error, because MySQL does not understand what the query means.  `INSERT IGNORE` ignores run-time errors, but the query has to compile before it can run.

And, let me repeat the advice to use parameterized queries.  If you had done so, your code would have worked much sooner.

EDIT:

If `device_id` should be unique in the table, then define a unique constraint:

```
alter table rr_emergency add constraint unq_emergency_device unique (device_id);
```

Then `insert ignore` will ignore any duplicate key errors.

Comment: Trying this, but still nothing: ```$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO rr_emergency(device_id, sensor_value, date_time) VALUES($device_id, $sensor_value, '$fdate')";```

Comment: Got it! Needed this: ```$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO rr_emergency(device_id, sensor_value, date_time) VALUES('$device_id', '$sensor_value', '$fdate')";```

Comment: Good answer Gordon, +1

Comment: One problem...I got it to insert in the table just fine. However, when the value is a duplicate, it still posts it, which was the entire point. I'm looking to have it post to the database when the ```device_id``` IS NOT already present in the table. What do I need to do to make this work?